# Display date and time comparing present date with past date in java

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I am using JodaTime to compare the dates

```
DateTime past = new DateTime(quitYear, quitMonth, quitDay, quitTimeHour, quitTimeMin);
DateTime today = new DateTime();
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays();
```

This gives me the number of days difference. How do i display the time difference aswell. For example it shows that the difference is 5:23(5 hours and 23 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get that from one query, you must do more operations.

Probably you can do this

```
        Duration duration = new Interval(past, today).toDuration();
        int days = duration.toStandardDays().getDays();
        int hours = duration.toStandardHours().getHours() - days * 24;
        int minutes = duration.toStandardMinutes().getMinutes() - days * 24 * 60 - hours * 60;
```

Comment: int minutes = duration.toStandardMinutes().getMinutes() - days * 24 - hours * 60; Should be: int minutes = duration.toStandardMinutes().getMinutes() - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);